# JBoss 6 AS with AOP throws StackOverflowError

Tags: jboss, aop, jboss6.x

I am using JBoss 6 AS and trying to add via AOP an interceptor to the classes in some package from a  deployed application. This is the scenario:

- I have an `app.jar` that contains the classes to which I want to add advices. This JAR also has some EJBs (ejb-jar.xml, jboss.xml).
- I created my on JBoss interceptor like this :

  ```
  package util;
  import org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.Invocation;
  import org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation;
  public class MyInterceptor implements org.jboss.aop.advice.Interceptor {
      @Override
      public Object invoke(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
          long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
          try {
              return invocation.invokeNext();
          } finally {
              long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
              System.out.println("MyInterceptor : " + endTime);
              if (invocation instanceof MethodInvocation) {
                  MethodInvocation mi = (MethodInvocation) invocation;
                  String clazz = "";
                  String method = "";
                  try {
                      clazz = mi.getTargetObject().getClass().toString();
                      method = mi.getMethod().getName();
                  } catch (Throwable e) {
                      System.out.println("Error when trying to get target info");
                  }
                  System.out.println("MyInterceptor : " + endTime);
              }
          }
      }

      @Override
      public String getName() {
          return "MyInterceptor";
      }
  }
  ```
- I created a `jboss-aop.xml` file that contains:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <aop xmlns="urn:jboss:aop-beans:1.0">
      <interceptor name="MyInterceptor"  class="util.MyInterceptor"/>
      <bind pointcut="execution(* my.app.*->*(..))">
          <interceptor-ref name="MyInterceptor"/>
      </bind>
  </aop>
  ```
- I have set `enableLoadTimeWeaving` (bootstrap/aop.xml)
- I have `pluggable-instrumentor.jar` in the right place (JBOSS/bin)
- I have started the server with the option `-javaagent:pluggable-instrumentor.jar`
- I have created a JAR file `interceptor.jar` where I put `MyInterceptor.class` and in its META-INF I've placed the `jboss-aop.xml` file

Now, that being said, the problem is that when I run my application and some method from any class from `my.app` package is being called the interceptor seems to intercept the call but it throws a nasty `StackOverflowError`. This is a part of my error stack:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.unwrapException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:345) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:321) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:214) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:190) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:534) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:496) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invokePropagateNotFound(SynchronousDispatcher.java:155) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:212) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:59) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.1.0.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at my.app.JoinPoint_invoke_N_5164114663869737738_3.invokeJoinpoint(JoinPoint_invoke_N_5164114663869737738_3.java) [:]
at my.app.MyInterceptor$MyInterceptorAdvisor.invoke_N_5164114663869737738(MyInterceptor$MyInterceptorAdvisor.java) [:]
at my.app.MyInterceptor.invoke(MyInterceptor.java) [:]
at my.app.JoinPoint_invoke_N_5164114663869737738_3.invokeNext(JoinPoint_invoke_N_5164114663869737738_3.java) [:]
at my.app.JoinPoint_invoke_N_5164114663869737738_3.invokeJoinpoint(JoinPoint_invoke_N_5164114663869737738_3.java) [:]
at my.app.MyInterceptor$MyInterceptorAdvisor.invoke_N_5164114663869737738(MyInterceptor$MyInterceptorAdvisor.java) [:]
at my.app.MyInterceptor.invoke(MyInterceptor.java) [:]
```

Basically what happens is that these four lines are being thrown until `StackOverflowError` gets raised:

```
at my.app.JoinPoint_invoke_N_5164114663869737738_3.invokeNext(JoinPoint_invoke_N_5164114663869737738_3.java) [:]
at my.app.JoinPoint_invoke_N_5164114663869737738_3.invokeJoinpoint(JoinPoint_invoke_N_5164114663869737738_3.java) [:]
at my.app.MyInterceptor$MyInterceptorAdvisor.invoke_N_5164114663869737738(MyInterceptor$MyInterceptorAdvisor.java) [:]
at my.app.MyInterceptor.invoke(MyInterceptor.java) [:]
```

If anyone had some similar problem any help would be appeciated!

Comment: Do you mean JBoss EAP 6?

Comment: i mean JBoss AS 6 ( the community distribution ) and NOT EAP 6 ( this would be the enterprise distribution based on JBoss AS 7 )

Comment: So basically JBoss 6.x IIUC?

Comment: Yes , that's correct. JBoss 6.1.0 to be accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i found the problem ... i put the interceptor on the same package my.app and not in util ... so eventually it was calling itself endlessly until the stack was full . So ... my bad

Comment: When you have gathered enough reputation points you should be able to accept your own answer and close the question.